# Why records arrive after 40 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

**ayetler Table** = 6500 rows

**fihristayet Table** = 13279 rows

Sql query :

```
SELECT ayetler.ayet_tr 
FROM fihristayet,ayetler 
WHERE (fihristayet.fihristAyet_ayet=ayetler.ayet_no AND 
       fihristayet.fihristAyet_sure_id=ayetler.sure_id) 
  AND fihristayet.fihristAyet_fihrist_id=354
```

I have 15 rows return. Why records arrive after 40 seconds

Comment: add indexes to your tables. WIthout indexes all records have to be walked and compared and depending on your disk speed that can be pretty slow. With indexes on the fields in your where statement your database server can optimise.

Comment: What time were you expecting?

Comment: This could be anything from a slow query (lack of indexes), to a bad DB configuration (memory, IO etc) - please at least supply schema information - query plan and some DB configuration information.

Comment: records need to arrive in no more than 3 seconds

Comment: @v3nqe 3 seconds? This should arrive even on a low end machine with good indexes within 100ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  So, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT a.ayet_tr
FROM fihristayet f JOIN
     ayetler a
     ON f.fihristAyet_ayet = a.ayet_no AND
        f.fihristAyet_sure_id = a.sure_id
WHERE f.fihristAyet_fihrist_id = 354;
```

Then you want indexes on `fihristayet(fihristAyet_fihrist_id, fihristAyet_ayet, fihristAyet_sure_id)` and `ayetler(ayet_no, sure_id)`.

Comment: `FROM fihristayet,ayetler`